# Uploadify + Castleproject Monorail: Ajax calls cannot be done while uploading

Tags: c#, ajax, blocking, uploadify, castle-monorail

I am working on a project using the uploadify jquery plugin and CastleProject Monorail as backend. The problem I get is that while uploading it seems to block the ajax calls (which are called in the meantime). The ajax are called after the upload is finished.

The strange thing is, when I implement uploadify in a new castleproject monorail project, ajax calls that are called in the meantime DO work.

There seems to be some setting which I cannot think of at the moment in the former project that causes the blocking. Web.config settings are the same.

Does anybody have an idea what can be the cause of this?

Thanks

**Update:**

I think I found the problem: As soon as the Session object has been used, the webserver blocks multiple requests. This to circumvent the more general problem of race conditions.

Is there some way to disable this so I can handle the race conditions myself?

Comment: are you using prototype for the monorail ajax calls?

Comment: both jquery and prototype (using jQuery's noConflict)

Comment: can you try removing prototype and using jQuery for the ajax calls instead? e.g. jQuery.get('/mycontroller/myaction', function(data){...})

Comment: also, what version of monorail are you using?

Comment: found the problem (but no solution), see update in question

Comment: about session concurrency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx not sure how to change this in monorail

Comment: see http://forum.castleproject.org/viewtopic.php?p=8711 for RC2 it's gonna be very hard to fix it. This is probably already fixed in trunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution / workaround, but it may not be applicable to every case. Thanks Mauricio Scheffer for giving directions.

Instead of using a monorail handler (i.e. a controller function) to handle the upload (or long running process), create a separate handler (ashx) outside of monorail to do your stuff.

This handler should implement the IReadOnlySessionState interface, so that it won't block multiple requests. The only catch is that in this handler you only may read from the session object and not to write to it.